# Spring Cloud Configuration Server Through Sidecar

Tags: spring-cloud

We are using spring cloud sidecar with a node.js application. It would be extremely useful if we could serve up configuration from the spring configuration server and make that configuration available to the node application.

I would like the sidecar to resolve any property place holders on behalf of the node application.

The sidecar already hits the configuration server and I know that the Environment in the sidecar WILL resolve all the property place holders. My problem is, how do I efficiently expose all those properties to the node application? I could create a simple rest endpoint that accepts a key and then returns `environment.getProperty(key)` but that would be extremely inefficient.

I am thinking that I could iterate over all property sources (I know that not all property sources can be enumerated), collect a unique set of the names and then turn around and call `environment.getProperty()` for each name....

But is there a better way?

I have to imagine this is functionality that others have needed when using Spring Cloud in a polyglot environment?

Comment: You could just ask the sidecar for the config server location and then send a request directly there. Is there something about the placeholders that means they have to be resolved locally?

Comment: If I get the property sources directly from the configuration server, I will have to implement logic in Javascript/Node to resolve the property place holders. If we introduce new services in other languages, they too would have to implement logic to resolve the place holders. Since the configuration server is a core infrastructure service, it would be nice if the place holders were resolved in the sidecar.

Comment: Or maybe the configuration server could resolve these using a query parameter to denote if the place holders should be resolved?

Comment: Interesting, the reason it currently does not is because those placeholders could be resolved from somewhere else in Spring's `Environment` (classpath config files, env vars, system properties, etc...). There's the possibility of unresolved placeholders. File an issue?

Comment: I will file an issue under the side car project, as this seem like a more appropriate place to handle the property place holders on behalf of the parent application.